# React - Property does not exist on type IntrinsicAttributes

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm new to React and am seeing this error which I can't figure how to resolve:

`Property classes does not exist on type IntrinsicAttributes`.

I have the following code:

```
class SeriesView extends React.Component<Props> {
    render() {

        return (
            <SeriesDetail classes={this.props.classes} />
        )
    }
}
```

And the `SeriesDetail` is declared as:

```
const SeriesDetail: React.FC<{}> = () => {
    //This just gets some payload
    const service = useGetSeriesService();

    if (service.status === 'loading') {
        return <div>Loading...</div>
    } else if (service.status === 'loaded') {
        const seriesData = service.payload[0]
        return (
            <div>
                <h1 className=""> 
                    {seriesData.description}
                </h1>
            </div>
            );

    } else if (service.status === 'error') {
        return <div>Oops!</div>
    } else {
        return <div></div>
    }

};
```

So its at the point `className=""` I want to be able to pass in something like `classes.clearStyle` which is set in `props`.

Any ideas on how I do this?

Also, being new to React, if there are any other suggestions, I'd really appreciate any guidance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to have "custom props" on your react components with typescript, you need to define them in the prop types:

```js
interface SeriesDetailProps {
  classes: {
    clearStyle: string;
  };
}

const SeriesDetail: React.FC<SeriesDetailProps> = (props) => {
 // ...
}
```

Only then you can pass these props and have proper type checking. It looks like you have already defined `Props` for your `SeriesView` component, so I guess you could adapt them for the `SeriesDetail` component.

Comment: Thanks - although to be honest I don't full understand. I don't want to declare another interface, just use whatever is `this.props.classes` i.e. `@material-ui/core`

Comment: how does your `Props` interfaces looks like (the one associated with `SeriesView`)?

Comment: That works - out of interest, why was the empty `{}` i.e. `React.FC<{}>` - thats an example I found some documentation (I think lol).
Also, if I wanted to pass in multiple interfaces, is that possible? Whats the syntax as I tried curly brackets and it didnt work.

Comment: `{}` just means „no props“. If you want to combine multiple interfaces you can use a union: `React.FC<InterfaceA & InterfaceB & InterfaceC>`

Comment: Thanks! Appreciated, I couldn't figure out that syntax.